# using $_GET with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have done a mod_rewrite :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/(.*) /b.php?n=$1&b=$2 [L,QSA]
```

it changes my url from this:

```
http://www.website.com/b.php?n=15&t=example
```

to this:

```
http://www.website.com/15/example
```

No images were working so I put this in my header:

```
<base href="/">
```

BOOM images work. However I have gifs that load from using the t and n variable in my url.

```
echo '<img src="gifs/' . $_GET["t"] . '/' . $_GET["n"] . '.gif">';
```

how do I get $_GET["t"] and $_GET["n"] in my new mod_rewrite url to show the image

Comment: Hopefully it's just to simplify your question, but it's not good to print out post or get variables directly without checking their content.

Comment: @insertusernamehere Sorry what do you mean?

Comment: You should not do something like `echo $_GET["t"]` as you don't know, what the user has send. Always check the content of `$_GET|$_POST` first before printing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to parse the URL by splitting on '/'.

using the rewrite explicitly removes them as $_GET parameters.

Look into $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']